# Nested if loops with conditional statements

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am using a random number that is between 1 and 350. depending on what the number will depends on what happen next. I am using if statements to determine the action.
Say random number id 15 it goes through the following.

```
   int x = Integer.parseInt(data.get(0));
    if(x <= 250){
        if(x <=201){ //do something
        }else if(x >= 101){// do something 
            }else if(x >= 1){//do something

                }
    } else{//Do something as number to big

    }
```

so hopefully if x is greater that 250 an action will be carried out as it is to big. But if between 1 and 250 it will go via the if statements.

How do I correct this as not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to match from *201* to *101*, you'll need a compounded conditional statement.

```java
if (x <= 201 && x >= 101)
```

The *&&* here is going to fail if either of those conditions are *false*.

*[Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators  (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)*.

So, your complete code would be the following.

```java
if (x <= 250) {
    if (x <= 201 && x >= 101) { //do something
        
    } else if (x >= 1) {//do something

    }
} else {//Do something as number to big

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of checks matter here.

```
if (x > 250) {
    //Do something as number to big
} else if (x >= 201) {
    // handle x between 201 an 250
} else if(x >= 101) {
    // handle x between 101 an 200
} else { 
    // handle x between 1 an 100
}
```